# bash variable disappearing not in loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have this piece in which the variable `TESTS_SUCEEDED` disappears or its value is unset. I saw many examples in which variables disappear due to subshell starting in loops, but couldn't find any clue about this behaviour.

```
${SRCDIR}/3rdParty/bin/alxdatabasemanager 
--create-database-with-name=TestAlexandriaDB || exit 1
Src/Tests/Functional/FunctionalTestLibalexandria
TESTS_SUCCEEDED="$?"

#Here variable exists
echo ${TESTS_SUCEEDED}

${SRCDIR}/3rdParty/bin/alxdatabasemanager 
--delete-database-with-name=TestAlexandriaDB || exit 1

#FIXME: Variable nonexisten here or value lost??!! Why?
exit ${TESTS_SUCCEDED}
```

Could anyone tell me what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know it disappeared? Maybe `exit 1` on a previous line exited your script before `exit ${TESTS_SUCCEDED}` had a chance to use it?

Answer (score 4):

You are having spelling issues: `TESTS_SUCCEEDED` and `TESTS_SUCEEDED` are not the same thing.

Let's line'em up, to clarify:

```
TESTS_SUCCEEDED
TESTS_SUCEEDED
```